# I want modal to appear only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I using jquery simplemodal.js with newsletter subscription regestration and I need to make it scroll triggered, appear not on every site and only when we first time visit website, disappear hen we cancel it or submit, and not appear any more.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('cruises') == -1){
    if (!newsletter) {
        var name = 'scroll_popup';
        if (sessionStorage[name] != 1 && window[name] != 1) {
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                var y_scroll = window.pageYOffset;
                var scroll_test = 150; 

                    if(y_scroll > scroll_test) {
                        $('#my_popup').modal({closeClass: 'modal-close'});
                    }
            });
            cancelPopup();
        }
    }
}

function cancelPopup() {
    var name = 'scroll_popup';
    try {
        sessionStorage.setItem(name, 1);
    } catch(e) {
        window[name] = 1;
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.js-cancel_popup', function(e) {
    cancelPopup();
});
```

when we first time coming to website and we click submit or cancel modal disappear and not appear when we scrolling

after cancel modal appear when we scrolling

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: i couldn't find any problem there, i just think that my thinking is wrong in general, im not good in js.

Comment: "not appear when scrolling" => check the value of y_scroll, the condition "y_scroll > scroll_test" and that $('#my_popup').length === 1.

Comment: it should appear once when we scrolling so that condition is needed but after scrolling it shouldn't  appear any more.

Comment: Move cancelPopup() after "if (y_scroll > scroll_test){...}" (inside the on).